# How to get a current index before return in eventFilter handler?

Tags: qt, eventfilter

When I move a current index with **Key_Up** or **Key_Down** in **treeView**, I found out that the moved current index is only applied after this line `return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);`. How can I get a newly moved index before `return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);` ? I tried to change the moved current index by manual with `currentIndex = currentIndex-1;` but it didn't work.

```
bool TipManager::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(watched == ui->treeView && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress){
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        QModelIndex currentIndex = ui->treeView->currentIndex();

        if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up )
        {
            //currentIndex = currentIndex-1;
        }
        if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down )
        {
            //currentIndex = currentIndex+1;
        }
        if(currentIndex.isValid())
        {
            ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex);
            trimCurrentPath(currentIndex);
        }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to guess the following currenIndex?

Comment: @eyllanesc because I want to show a directory of the current selected file in **treeView**. But the new directory path is applied after moving the index once more (It means it applies the previous directory path).

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why do not you use the currentChanged signal? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#currentChanged

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried : `connect(this,SIGNAL(ui->treeView->currentChanged()),this,SLOT(this->indexChanged()));` in .cpp. `protected slots:
    void indexChanged();` in .h

Comment: but it doesn't work

Comment: @eyllanesc what I have found so far is that `connect` cannot be applied to GUI (a dialog made in _ui_). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first pass the event down, then check the index:

```
bool TipManager::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    bool const ret = QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);

    if(watched == ui->treeView && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress){
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        QModelIndex currentIndex = ui->treeView->currentIndex();

        if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up )
        {
            //currentIndex = currentIndex-1;
        }
        if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down )
        {
            //currentIndex = currentIndex+1;
        }
        if(currentIndex.isValid())
        {
            ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex);
            trimCurrentPath(currentIndex);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But I guess that actually the index is changed only after *leaving* your `eventFilter(watched, event)`...